# Using two-sample K-S test for the same time-series data

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have time-series data which is a recording of neural activity in a neuron before and after some stimuli (I know the specific time when the stimuli was introduced). I'm considering using the two-sample K-S test on the distributions of neural signal strength before and after the stimuli to check whether there is a statistically significant difference between them, which would imply that this neuron responded to the stimuli.

I'm new to statistics, and I'm not sure whether this data would violate some of the assumptions of the K-S test. I've read that K-S test assumes the independence of the two distributions being compared, would this mean that comparing the distributions of signals from the same neuron would break this assumption, since the activity from after the stimuli might be dependent on the activity from before? Are there any other assumptions of the K-S test that this data might be violating? If so, is there any pre-processing of the data I could do, or are there any other statistical tests that might be better suited?

Comment: The problem indeed is lack of independence: the KS test assumes all *individual* data points are independent.  That's not the case for neural activity (nor is it usually the case for any time series).  Instead, search our site for questions about "change points" or "structural breaks."

Comment: I see. I'm assuming it would still be violated (in this case due to two distributions being correlated) if I would take an average of individual data points before and after the stimuli, and perform a KS test on distributions of those 2 averages across all datasets (all datasets are of the same neuron, but different individuals)? Perhaps to ensure independence I could calculate after how many time steps the data points stop being significantly correlated, and ensure that there is at least that much distance between the two windows in which I calculate averages for before and after the stimuli?